# CSS <article> height issue

Tags: html, css, article

I need your help to fix a CSS problem.

I am learning HTML/CSS and as you can see I have a problem with my  content that jumps overs the  div section.

I don't know how to make the  section unlimited height. 
I tried min-height but without success ..

Please respond very soon because I have to complete exercise in just 4 days.

Thank you

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr"> 
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  
  <meta name="keywords" content="" />
     <meta name="description" content="" />
  
<style>

body {
     padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #e2dede;
}
#container {
    width: 980px;
 min-height: 1200px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}

header {
    width: 980px;
 height: 125px;
 background-color: yellow;
}

#content {
    width: 980px;
 min-height: 1200px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}

#slider {
    width: 980px;
 min-height: 325px;
 background-color: blue;
}

aside {
    width: 240px;
 min-height: 800px;
 background-color: orange;
 float: left;
}

nav {
    width: 200px;
 min-height: 445px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 margin: 20px;
 clear: float;
}

article {
    width: 500px;
 min-height: 800px;
 background-color: white;
 float: left;
}

#right-col {
    width: 240px;
 min-height: 870px;
 float: left;
 background-color: yellow;
}

footer {
    width: 980px;
 min-height: 200px;
 background-color: grey;
}

</style>
</head>
<body> 


   <div id="container">
   

      <header>
      </header>
     

      <div id="content">
   

    <div id="slider">
    </div>
   

    <aside>
        <nav> 
     </nav>
    </aside>
    
     
    <article>
     <p>
      Hac ita persuasione reducti intra moenia bellatores obseratis undique portarum aditibus, propugnaculis insistebant et pinnis, congesta undique saxa telaque habentes in promptu, ut si quis se proripuisset interius, multitudine missilium sterneretur et lapidum.

      Incenderat autem audaces usque ad insaniam homines ad haec, quae nefariis egere conatibus, Luscus quidam curator urbis subito visus: eosque ut heiulans baiolorum praecentor ad expediendum quod orsi sunt incitans vocibus crebris. qui haut longe postea ideo vivus exustus est.

      Omitto iuris dictionem in libera civitate contra leges senatusque consulta; caedes relinquo; libidines praetereo, quarum acerbissimum extat indicium et ad insignem memoriam turpitudinis et paene ad iustum odium imperii nostri, quod constat nobilissimas virgines se in puteos abiecisse et morte voluntaria necessariam turpitudinem depulisse. Nec haec idcirco omitto, quod non gravissima sint, sed quia nunc sine teste dico.

      Accedat huc suavitas quaedam oportet sermonum atque morum, haudquaquam mediocre condimentum amicitiae. Tristitia autem et in omni re severitas habet illa quidem gravitatem, sed amicitia remissior esse debet et liberior et dulcior et ad omnem comitatem facilitatemque proclivior.

      Tempore quo primis auspiciis in mundanum fulgorem surgeret victura dum erunt homines Roma, ut augeretur sublimibus incrementis, foedere pacis aeternae Virtus convenit atque Fortuna plerumque dissidentes, quarum si altera defuisset, ad perfectam non venerat summitatem.

      Pandente itaque viam fatorum sorte tristissima, qua praestitutum erat eum vita et imperio spoliari, itineribus interiectis permutatione iumentorum emensis venit Petobionem oppidum Noricorum, ubi reseratae sunt insidiarum latebrae omnes, et Barbatio repente apparuit comes, qui sub eo domesticis praefuit, cum Apodemio agente in rebus milites ducens, quos beneficiis suis oppigneratos elegerat imperator certus nec praemiis nec miseratione ulla posse deflecti.

      Quid? qui se etiam nunc subsidiis patrimonii aut amicorum liberalitate sustentant, hos perire patiemur? An, si qui frui publico non potuit per hostem, hic tegitur ipsa lege censoria; quem is frui non sinit, qui est, etiamsi non appellatur, hostis, huic ferri auxilium non oportet? Retinete igitur in provincia diutius eum, qui de sociis cum hostibus, de civibus cum sociis faciat pactiones, qui hoc etiam se pluris esse quam collegam putet, quod ille vos tristia voltuque deceperit, ipse numquam se minus quam erat, nequam esse simularit. Piso autem alio quodam modo gloriatur se brevi tempore perfecisse, ne Gabinius unus omnium nequissimus existimaretur.

      Duplexque isdem diebus acciderat malum, quod et Theophilum insontem atrox interceperat casus, et Serenianus dignus exsecratione cunctorum, innoxius, modo non reclamante publico vigore, discessit.

      Coactique aliquotiens nostri pedites ad eos persequendos scandere clivos sublimes etiam si lapsantibus plantis fruticeta prensando vel dumos ad vertices venerint summos, inter arta tamen et invia nullas acies explicare permissi nec firmare nisu valido gressus: hoste discursatore rupium abscisa volvente, ruinis ponderum inmanium consternuntur, aut ex necessitate ultima fortiter dimicante, superati periculose per prona discedunt.

      Nec vox accusatoris ulla licet subditicii in his malorum quaerebatur acervis ut saltem specie tenus crimina praescriptis legum committerentur, quod aliquotiens fecere principes saevi: sed quicquid Caesaris implacabilitati sedisset, id velut fas iusque perpensum confestim urgebatur impleri.
     </p>
     <p>
      Hac ita persuasione reducti intra moenia bellatores obseratis undique portarum aditibus, propugnaculis insistebant et pinnis, congesta undique saxa telaque habentes in promptu, ut si quis se proripuisset interius, multitudine missilium sterneretur et lapidum.

      Incenderat autem audaces usque ad insaniam homines ad haec, quae nefariis egere conatibus, Luscus quidam curator urbis subito visus: eosque ut heiulans baiolorum praecentor ad expediendum quod orsi sunt incitans vocibus crebris. qui haut longe postea ideo vivus exustus est.

      Omitto iuris dictionem in libera civitate contra leges senatusque consulta; caedes relinquo; libidines praetereo, quarum acerbissimum extat indicium et ad insignem memoriam turpitudinis et paene ad iustum odium imperii nostri, quod constat nobilissimas virgines se in puteos abiecisse et morte voluntaria necessariam turpitudinem depulisse. Nec haec idcirco omitto, quod non gravissima sint, sed quia nunc sine teste dico.

      Accedat huc suavitas quaedam oportet sermonum atque morum, haudquaquam mediocre condimentum amicitiae. Tristitia autem et in omni re severitas habet illa quidem gravitatem, sed amicitia remissior esse debet et liberior et dulcior et ad omnem comitatem facilitatemque proclivior.

      Tempore quo primis auspiciis in mundanum fulgorem surgeret victura dum erunt homines Roma, ut augeretur sublimibus incrementis, foedere pacis aeternae Virtus convenit atque Fortuna plerumque dissidentes, quarum si altera defuisset, ad perfectam non venerat summitatem.

      Pandente itaque viam fatorum sorte tristissima, qua praestitutum erat eum vita et imperio spoliari, itineribus interiectis permutatione iumentorum emensis venit Petobionem oppidum Noricorum, ubi reseratae sunt insidiarum latebrae omnes, et Barbatio repente apparuit comes, qui sub eo domesticis praefuit, cum Apodemio agente in rebus milites ducens, quos beneficiis suis oppigneratos elegerat imperator certus nec praemiis nec miseratione ulla posse deflecti.

      Quid? qui se etiam nunc subsidiis patrimonii aut amicorum liberalitate sustentant, hos perire patiemur? An, si qui frui publico non potuit per hostem, hic tegitur ipsa lege censoria; quem is frui non sinit, qui est, etiamsi non appellatur, hostis, huic ferri auxilium non oportet? Retinete igitur in provincia diutius eum, qui de sociis cum hostibus, de civibus cum sociis faciat pactiones, qui hoc etiam se pluris esse quam collegam putet, quod ille vos tristia voltuque deceperit, ipse numquam se minus quam erat, nequam esse simularit. Piso autem alio quodam modo gloriatur se brevi tempore perfecisse, ne Gabinius unus omnium nequissimus existimaretur.

      Duplexque isdem diebus acciderat malum, quod et Theophilum insontem atrox interceperat casus, et Serenianus dignus exsecratione cunctorum, innoxius, modo non reclamante publico vigore, discessit.

      Coactique aliquotiens nostri pedites ad eos persequendos scandere clivos sublimes etiam si lapsantibus plantis fruticeta prensando vel dumos ad vertices venerint summos, inter arta tamen et invia nullas acies explicare permissi nec firmare nisu valido gressus: hoste discursatore rupium abscisa volvente, ruinis ponderum inmanium consternuntur, aut ex necessitate ultima fortiter dimicante, superati periculose per prona discedunt.

      Nec vox accusatoris ulla licet subditicii in his malorum quaerebatur acervis ut saltem specie tenus crimina praescriptis legum committerentur, quod aliquotiens fecere principes saevi: sed quicquid Caesaris implacabilitati sedisset, id velut fas iusque perpensum confestim urgebatur impleri.
     </p>
    </article>
    
    <div id="right-col">
    </div>
   
            </div>
   

            <footer>
   </footer>
   
 </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

thank you :-)

Comment: To clarify: You are trying to get it so one of your divs expands in height so the bottom of the div matches the bottom of your `<article>` element?

Comment: The <article> section should be unlimited html content and still display inside the template. Right now, when I put long paragraphs the <article> content (the div with background-color: White) goes over the <footer> which in not good at all.. I hope you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your `article` CSS to prevent it from going past your footer:

```
height: 870px;
overflow: auto;
```

Here is a full example:

```css
body {
     padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #e2dede;
}
#container {
    width: 980px;
 min-height: 1200px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}

header {
    width: 980px;
 height: 125px;
 background-color: yellow;
}

#content {
    width: 980px;
 min-height: 1200px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}

#slider {
    width: 980px;
 min-height: 325px;
 background-color: blue;
}

aside {
    width: 240px;
 min-height: 870px;
 background-color: orange;
 float: left;
}

nav {
    width: 200px;
 min-height: 445px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 margin: 20px;
 clear: float;
}

article {
    height: 870px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 500px;
    min-height: 800px;
    background-color: white;
    float: left;
}

#right-col {
    width: 240px;
 min-height: 870px;
 float: left;
 background-color: yellow;
}

footer {
    width: 980px;
 min-height: 200px;
 background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr"> 
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  
  <meta name="keywords" content="" />
     <meta name="description" content="" />
</head>
<body> 


   <div id="container">
   

      <header>
      </header>
     

      <div id="content">
   

    <div id="slider">
    </div>
   

    <aside>
        <nav> 
     </nav>
    </aside>
    
     
    <article>
     <p>
      Hac ita persuasione reducti intra moenia bellatores obseratis undique portarum aditibus, propugnaculis insistebant et pinnis, congesta undique saxa telaque habentes in promptu, ut si quis se proripuisset interius, multitudine missilium sterneretur et lapidum.

      Incenderat autem audaces usque ad insaniam homines ad haec, quae nefariis egere conatibus, Luscus quidam curator urbis subito visus: eosque ut heiulans baiolorum praecentor ad expediendum quod orsi sunt incitans vocibus crebris. qui haut longe postea ideo vivus exustus est.

      Omitto iuris dictionem in libera civitate contra leges senatusque consulta; caedes relinquo; libidines praetereo, quarum acerbissimum extat indicium et ad insignem memoriam turpitudinis et paene ad iustum odium imperii nostri, quod constat nobilissimas virgines se in puteos abiecisse et morte voluntaria necessariam turpitudinem depulisse. Nec haec idcirco omitto, quod non gravissima sint, sed quia nunc sine teste dico.

      Accedat huc suavitas quaedam oportet sermonum atque morum, haudquaquam mediocre condimentum amicitiae. Tristitia autem et in omni re severitas habet illa quidem gravitatem, sed amicitia remissior esse debet et liberior et dulcior et ad omnem comitatem facilitatemque proclivior.

      Tempore quo primis auspiciis in mundanum fulgorem surgeret victura dum erunt homines Roma, ut augeretur sublimibus incrementis, foedere pacis aeternae Virtus convenit atque Fortuna plerumque dissidentes, quarum si altera defuisset, ad perfectam non venerat summitatem.

      Pandente itaque viam fatorum sorte tristissima, qua praestitutum erat eum vita et imperio spoliari, itineribus interiectis permutatione iumentorum emensis venit Petobionem oppidum Noricorum, ubi reseratae sunt insidiarum latebrae omnes, et Barbatio repente apparuit comes, qui sub eo domesticis praefuit, cum Apodemio agente in rebus milites ducens, quos beneficiis suis oppigneratos elegerat imperator certus nec praemiis nec miseratione ulla posse deflecti.

      Quid? qui se etiam nunc subsidiis patrimonii aut amicorum liberalitate sustentant, hos perire patiemur? An, si qui frui publico non potuit per hostem, hic tegitur ipsa lege censoria; quem is frui non sinit, qui est, etiamsi non appellatur, hostis, huic ferri auxilium non oportet? Retinete igitur in provincia diutius eum, qui de sociis cum hostibus, de civibus cum sociis faciat pactiones, qui hoc etiam se pluris esse quam collegam putet, quod ille vos tristia voltuque deceperit, ipse numquam se minus quam erat, nequam esse simularit. Piso autem alio quodam modo gloriatur se brevi tempore perfecisse, ne Gabinius unus omnium nequissimus existimaretur.

      Duplexque isdem diebus acciderat malum, quod et Theophilum insontem atrox interceperat casus, et Serenianus dignus exsecratione cunctorum, innoxius, modo non reclamante publico vigore, discessit.

      Coactique aliquotiens nostri pedites ad eos persequendos scandere clivos sublimes etiam si lapsantibus plantis fruticeta prensando vel dumos ad vertices venerint summos, inter arta tamen et invia nullas acies explicare permissi nec firmare nisu valido gressus: hoste discursatore rupium abscisa volvente, ruinis ponderum inmanium consternuntur, aut ex necessitate ultima fortiter dimicante, superati periculose per prona discedunt.

      Nec vox accusatoris ulla licet subditicii in his malorum quaerebatur acervis ut saltem specie tenus crimina praescriptis legum committerentur, quod aliquotiens fecere principes saevi: sed quicquid Caesaris implacabilitati sedisset, id velut fas iusque perpensum confestim urgebatur impleri.
     </p>
     <p>
      Hac ita persuasione reducti intra moenia bellatores obseratis undique portarum aditibus, propugnaculis insistebant et pinnis, congesta undique saxa telaque habentes in promptu, ut si quis se proripuisset interius, multitudine missilium sterneretur et lapidum.

      Incenderat autem audaces usque ad insaniam homines ad haec, quae nefariis egere conatibus, Luscus quidam curator urbis subito visus: eosque ut heiulans baiolorum praecentor ad expediendum quod orsi sunt incitans vocibus crebris. qui haut longe postea ideo vivus exustus est.

      Omitto iuris dictionem in libera civitate contra leges senatusque consulta; caedes relinquo; libidines praetereo, quarum acerbissimum extat indicium et ad insignem memoriam turpitudinis et paene ad iustum odium imperii nostri, quod constat nobilissimas virgines se in puteos abiecisse et morte voluntaria necessariam turpitudinem depulisse. Nec haec idcirco omitto, quod non gravissima sint, sed quia nunc sine teste dico.

      Accedat huc suavitas quaedam oportet sermonum atque morum, haudquaquam mediocre condimentum amicitiae. Tristitia autem et in omni re severitas habet illa quidem gravitatem, sed amicitia remissior esse debet et liberior et dulcior et ad omnem comitatem facilitatemque proclivior.

      Tempore quo primis auspiciis in mundanum fulgorem surgeret victura dum erunt homines Roma, ut augeretur sublimibus incrementis, foedere pacis aeternae Virtus convenit atque Fortuna plerumque dissidentes, quarum si altera defuisset, ad perfectam non venerat summitatem.

      Pandente itaque viam fatorum sorte tristissima, qua praestitutum erat eum vita et imperio spoliari, itineribus interiectis permutatione iumentorum emensis venit Petobionem oppidum Noricorum, ubi reseratae sunt insidiarum latebrae omnes, et Barbatio repente apparuit comes, qui sub eo domesticis praefuit, cum Apodemio agente in rebus milites ducens, quos beneficiis suis oppigneratos elegerat imperator certus nec praemiis nec miseratione ulla posse deflecti.

      Quid? qui se etiam nunc subsidiis patrimonii aut amicorum liberalitate sustentant, hos perire patiemur? An, si qui frui publico non potuit per hostem, hic tegitur ipsa lege censoria; quem is frui non sinit, qui est, etiamsi non appellatur, hostis, huic ferri auxilium non oportet? Retinete igitur in provincia diutius eum, qui de sociis cum hostibus, de civibus cum sociis faciat pactiones, qui hoc etiam se pluris esse quam collegam putet, quod ille vos tristia voltuque deceperit, ipse numquam se minus quam erat, nequam esse simularit. Piso autem alio quodam modo gloriatur se brevi tempore perfecisse, ne Gabinius unus omnium nequissimus existimaretur.

      Duplexque isdem diebus acciderat malum, quod et Theophilum insontem atrox interceperat casus, et Serenianus dignus exsecratione cunctorum, innoxius, modo non reclamante publico vigore, discessit.

      Coactique aliquotiens nostri pedites ad eos persequendos scandere clivos sublimes etiam si lapsantibus plantis fruticeta prensando vel dumos ad vertices venerint summos, inter arta tamen et invia nullas acies explicare permissi nec firmare nisu valido gressus: hoste discursatore rupium abscisa volvente, ruinis ponderum inmanium consternuntur, aut ex necessitate ultima fortiter dimicante, superati periculose per prona discedunt.

      Nec vox accusatoris ulla licet subditicii in his malorum quaerebatur acervis ut saltem specie tenus crimina praescriptis legum committerentur, quod aliquotiens fecere principes saevi: sed quicquid Caesaris implacabilitati sedisset, id velut fas iusque perpensum confestim urgebatur impleri.
     </p>
    </article>
    
    <div id="right-col">
    </div>
   
            </div>
   

            <footer>
   </footer>
   
 </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! That is nice :-)  I will try it on my site right away.

Comment: I am new to this site. Am I supposed to rate you?

Comment: @fendert12 Yes if you would be so kind! Mark the question as "accepted" by clicking the gray checkmark next to it, and also mark it as "helpful" by using the up arrow (even though your vote won't be public until you get more reputation, it will still keep track of it!)

Comment: I did both :-) Thanks.